# Error occur while rendering Partial View in PageModel View Asp.net Core application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I created simple partial view in shared folder. 
But when i render it in index.cshtml by using partial tag it gives an error.

> Error: InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'CoreWeb.Pages.IndexModel', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'CoreWeb.Pages.Shared._PartialTestModel'.

I used `<partial name="_PartialTest">` tag for rendering

Partial view location

[image]

partial view content

[image]

Rendering in index.cshtml

[image]

Startup.cs file changes related to PartialView

[image]

Error

[image]

Comment: Please add errors, html etc. as text instead of images of them

Comment: ok noted for next question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `<partial>` declaration, you need to pass an appropriate model, in this case, an instance of `_PartialTestModel`:

```
<partial name="_PartialTest" model="@new _PartialTestModel()" />
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/partial-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-3.1.